# Consuming External Provider Tokens on Asp.net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have enabled login with `Facebook`, `Google` and `Twitter` in an Asp.Net core project. I am also saving the corresponding tokens to table `AspNetUserTokens`. How can I retrieve Twitter tokens, for example, to access Twitter API on behalf of a user; without having this user log into Twitter or even being logged in to my application at the moment I am using Twitter API?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into the SignInManager but the right place to look for it was the UserManager:

```
 var accessToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Twitter", "access_token");
 var accessTokenSecret = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Twitter", "access_token_secret");
```